# How to hide a value based on the saved value of a document?

Tags: xpages

So lets say I have a form with a field, if the field equals S, a button is displayed, if not it is hidden.

What I would like to do is not display the button until the form is saved successfully with the field set to S.  What I am getting now is if I do a submit and fail to save, the button still displays, because the field is set to S, even though its not saved in the back end document.

I am using something like:

```
rendered="#{javascript:(document1.getItemValueString('field_X') == 'S')}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is change the render as follows and everything works perfect.

```
rendered="#{javascript:var nd:NotesDocument=document1.getDocument();(nd.getItemValueString('field_X') == 'S')}"
```

Posted the question and figured it out right after.

Comment: Just to clarify further, that's because `document1.getDocument()` will get the backend document without applying any updates made in the `dominoDocument` datasource. `document1.getDocument(true)` would apply the update, so "field_x" would always be "S"